# Trigger ripple effect on Material Bootstrap from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, material-design, jquery-events

How can I trigger the ripple effect from my Javascript on the Material Bootstrap?

Tried several events and none seems to trigger it.

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="toTrigger">Colored</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnTrigger">Trigger Button Colored</button>
```

Javascript

```
$('#btnTrigger').click(function(e){
   $('#toTrigger').trigger( 'mousedown, mouseup, click' );
   $('#toTrigger').trigger( e );
   $('#toTrigger').find('.ripple-wrapper').trigger('mousedown, mouseup, click'); 
   $('#toTrigger').find('.ripple-wrapper').trigger(e);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qw7g63o/)